# Tensorflow summary writer doesn't work when using keras.callbacks.TensorBoard

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I was using tensorflow2.13 and keras to train model. I'm trying to write the roc curve into tensorboard in addition to the TensorBoard_callback.

```
    image_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(run_logdir, 'ROC_curve'))
    tensorboard_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_logdir,
                                                 update_freq=50,
                                                 histogram_freq=1000,)
    try:
        history = model.fit(
            train_set,
            epochs=epochs,
            # validation_data=val_set,
            callbacks=[metrics_callback,
                       lr_scheduler,
                       early_stopping,
                       diy_checkpoints,
                       tensorboard_cb,
                       ],
            class_weight={0:1, 1:2}
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ...
```

The `metrics_callback` is a self defined callback, which has `on_epoch_end` like this:

```
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        ...
        plt.show()
        # Save the plot to a BytesIO object
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
        plt.close()
        buf.seek(0)

        # Convert buffer to tensor
        image = tf.image.decode_png(buf.getvalue(), channels=4)
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)  # Make it batched
        with image_writer.as_default():
            whether_saved_fig = tf.summary.image("ROC", image, step=epoch)
            print(f"try logging ROC: {whether_saved_fig}")
```

and the print shows tf.summary.image returns a 'False'. Also I notice that the v2 files is 78 bytes after it was created by `tf.summary.create_file_writer`, and if the image is not successfully written, the file remains to be 78 bytes and no modification occurs on it.

I've tried to use the `with image_writer.as_default()` clause directly after the definition, and it seems to work properly.

I tried:

- using writer.set_as_default() before fitting
- using with writer.as_default to enclude the fitting
  But I can't write to the summary during the fitting, and the print is always "False".

After excluding the `tensorboard_cb` in `model.fit`, the summary writer works normally. So it seems that `create_summary_writer` can't be used if one already have the `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` callback included. But I didn't see this in keras's document, and I'm not sure if keras was intended to be used like I do above.